# How to rotate array elements backwards

Tags: java

I would like to know how could I take in a negative value for d in the following code. This means, how could I traverse the array backwards and rotate its elements.

```
catchArray(int [] arr, int d)
{
    int [] bArr = new int[arr.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < bArr.length; i++)
    {
        bArr[(i + d) % bArr.length] = arr[i];
    }

    return bArr;
}
```

This is my answer for LeetCode Rotate Array assignment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried using a negative value for `d`?

Comment: I dont get the right index rotation and therefore out of bound.

Answer (score 1):

Just normalize "d" at the start of the program. If it's negative, then correct it.

Let's say the array length is 10 and d is -1.  You'd get the same rotation if length was 10 and d was 9.  That's all the adjustment at the start of the function is doing.

```
catchArray(int [] arr, int d)
{
    d = d % arr.length;
    if (d < 0)
    {
        d += arr.length;
    }

    int [] bArr = new int[arr.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < bArr.length; i++)
    {
        bArr[(i + d) % bArr.length] = arr[i];
    }

    return bArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is e.g. size 10, then a -1 rotation is the same as a +9 rotation.

In Java, the `%` remainder operator will return a negative value, if the quotient is negative, e.g. `-12 % 10` and `-2 % 10` will both return `-2`.

So, to get a normalized rotation value, we do this:

```
MIN_VALUE <= d <= MAX_VALUE

d % size  ->  -size < d < size

+ size    ->  0 < d < size * 2

% size    ->  0 <= d < size  (normalized range)
```

Combined:

```
d = (d % arr.length + arr.length) % arr.length
```

That normalizes `d` to rotate less than one full round to the right.

```
static int[] catchArray(int[] arr, int d) {
    d = (d % arr.length + arr.length) % arr.length;
    int[] bArr = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        bArr[(i + d) % arr.length] = arr[i];
    }
    return bArr;
}
```

*Tests*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, -8)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, -2)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, -1)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, 0)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, 1)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, 2)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(catchArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, 8)));
```

*Output*

```
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```